# I receive an error that a record is in use when using a checkbox widget

Tags: google-app-maker

This is the error I receive:

```
E Tue Jul 11 15:48:12 GMT-600 2017
Error: Equipment ID "EXAMPLE-GRAV001" is in use.
E Tue Jul 11 15:48:12 GMT-600 2017
Modifying records: (Error) : Equipment ID "EXAMPLE-GRAV001" is in use.
E Tue Jul 11 15:48:12 GMT-600 2017 Modifying records failed.
```

What determines if a record is "in use"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was being thrown by a custom script in the onSave event of my datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the solution, but the cause of this error is that Equipment ID is probably a primary key, and you're trying to update a record to have the same ID.